# GDB : compute double with print

Tags: c++, gdb

I would like to make some computation with gdb when my program is at a breakpoint.

But here is my problem :

```
(gdb) call 2,6*2
$26 = 12
```

It doesn't compute at all double.

How can I say gdb to compute doubles ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't you mean `2.6*2`? I.e. use the dot instead of the comma.

Comment: when i do this  it returns an error : it doesn't understand the dot

Comment: What is the error message? Works just fine for me: `(gdb) call 2.6 * 2` - `$1 = 5.1999999999999993`

Answer (score 1):

> `(gdb) call 2,6*2`
>   `$26 = 12`
>   It doesn't compute at all double.

It's not supposed to: you gave the GDB `call` command a comma-expression, which it correctly evaluated.

You probably want:

```
(gdb) print 2.6 * 2
$1 = 5.1999999999999993
```

or

```
(gdb) call 2.6 * 2
$2 = 5.1999999999999993
```